# Compare a struct in a map

Tags: c++, struct, compare, maps

I want to map a struct(key) to an int(value). Then I want to find a value given a key (struct).

```
typedef struct {
  int  a, b; 
} TechId;  

struct our_cmp {
  bool operator() ( TechId a, TechId b ) const
  { return std::make_pair(a.a,a.b) > std::make_pair(b.a, b.b) ; }

};

int main() {
std::map<TechId, int, our_cmp> mymap;

TechId x;

if(mymap.find(x)) {
  printf("found");
}

}
```

There is a find function but I guess it is only for string/ints etc? Is there a possibility to adapt it to my struct?

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you using where you learned about `printf`, and to write code like`typedef struct { }`? If your goal is to learn current, modern C++ you should throw it away [and get a better C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), that doesn't send you in the wrong direction of writing prehistoric C instead of C++.

Comment: why do you guess?  What makes you beleive it would only work for strings and integers?

Comment: nobody can remember all the standard library, you need a reference to look such things up. I recommend this one https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find. It even includes an example of finding an element in a map of custom types

Comment: I learned a little bit C and now trying C++. I know its a bit messy, it is hard to just stay in one language

Comment: "it is hard to just stay in one language" why? Its harder to switch between two different languages when you arent familiar with either of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the iterator returned by `find` with the `end()` iterator of the map. If they are not equal, the element you searched for was found:

```cpp
if (mymap.find(x) != mymap.end()) {
    printf("found");
}
```

Since C++20, you could also use the [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains) member function to do the same thing:

```cpp
if (mymap.contains(x)) {
    printf("found");
}
```

Comment: Because of my allocator (our_cmp) the compiler says: ‘class std::map<TechId, int, our_cmp>’ has no member named ‘contains’...

But without the comparing structure I cant map my struct. Maybe I have to write my own "find" function?

Comment: @Atoptix Allocator is not related, nor is comparator. `contains` is only available since C++20, you probably would have to enable it in your compiler. But the first version should work in any version of C++, it was always there.

Comment: @Atoptix As mentioned in the answer, `contains` is only available since C++20.  If you are using a version prior to C++20, then just use what we all used before C++20: `if(mymap.find(x) != mymap.end())`  as is also mentioned in the answer.  Why would you write your own `find` when there is already one that works?